# Insert rails values into Open Graph meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm trying to supply information from my Rails app to Facebook via it's Open Graph api but I can't get the following to insert using the #{} within double quotes. When I look at the output html it's just as seen below rather than inserting the Rails values.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="#{[@miniature.name.html_safe, @user.name].join(' by ')}"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="#{request.original_url}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="#{@collection.photo.url(:thumb)}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= [@miniature.name.html_safe, @user.name].join(' by ') %>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= @collection.photo.url(:thumb) %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use <%= %> tag instead of using #{}.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= [@miniature.name.html_safe, @user.name].join(' by ') %>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= @collection.photo.url(:thumb) %>"/>
```

Comment: oh! our answers got clashed... :P

Comment: That was only a few seconds difference :)